# Construct countable Boolean algebra

Tags: model-theory, boolean-algebra

How can I construct a countably infinite Boolean algebra with $n$ atoms, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I think the periodic sequences form a (the) countable atomless Boolean algebra, but how does this help?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: every boolean algebra is isomorphic to an algebra of sets. What happens if you add together (and generate algebra with) two algebras of sets with disjoint universes?

Answer (score 1):

Take the countable atomless Boolean algebra $B$ and let $A$ be the Boolean algebra $2^n$ generated by the atoms $a_1, \ldots, a_n$. Then, the product $B \times A$ is countably infinite and has as atoms $(0,a_1), \ldots, (0,a_n)$.